# Composite Beam Theory - Calculating torsion and beam deflection of a composite beam made up of a pipe inside a pipe

Tags: torque, beam, bending, composite

I am trying to calculate two things. First the beam deflection of my model after bending and second angle of twist after applying torque.
My model is composed of two tubes (cylindrical hollow beams). The smaller tube fits right inside the bigger tube. Small tube is made up of steel. The larger tube (by diameter) is made up of plastic. How would I go about these calculations? I know how to do the calculation if the materials were the same, but because they are not I am not sure how. I am attaching a imgur link of a picture of the model.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI18B.jpg

Comment: Assuming a tight fit, so the elastic shortening/lengthening will be identical for both materials. Then transform one material to the other using compatibility equations delta(i) = PL/E(i)A(i), delta(j) = PL/E(j)A(j), and set delta(i) = delta(j) to transformed area A(i) = A(j)*E(j)/E(i). Note that you need to maintain the centroid of the tube before and after the transformation in calculating the composite geometric properties.

Comment: are the outer and the inner tubes bonded together? That would have a significant impact on both the bending and torsion. Also can the properties of the tube be considered isotropic? And finally, do you expect the deformation to be large? (without numerical data its not possible to tell). Also it would be helpful, if you showed how you'd do it, so that other contributors can be more helpful.

Comment: A good approximation might be considering just the steel tube stiffness, if it is much larger than the plastic tube stiffness.